# HTML Table Not Updating With CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I am attempting to make a table that has the equivalent of the Bootstrap table-hover feature along with the table-striped feature. However, the CSS does not seem to be applying properly. The `th` styling is applying however none of the rows are. Additionally, I know the `toAppend` lines should probably be more clear but that is not my current concern.

This is what the table currently looks like:

[image]

**JavaScript:**

```
 function fortniteSearch(data) {
  // data to retrieve data / construct table
  const tableCells = [
  {category: "lifeTimeStats", stats: [8, 9, 10, 11, 7, 2, 4, 5]},
  {category: "stats", subcategory: "p2", stats: ["top1", "winRatio", "kills", "kd", "kpg", "matches", "top10", "top25"]},
  {category: "stats", subcategory: "p10", stats: ["top1", "winRatio", "kills", "kd", "kpg", "matches", "top5", "top12"]},
  {category: "stats", subcategory: "p9", stats: ["top1", "winRatio", "kills", "kd", "kpg", "matches", "top3", "top6"]}];

  // cell labels and flag
  const gameModes = ["OVERALL:", "SOLO:", "DUO:", "SQUADS:"];

  // check for errors
  if(data.error !== undefined)
    alert("Player not found!");

  else {
    // set player name and image
    $("#playerName").val(data.IGN);
    $("#playerIcon").attr("src", "/images/avatar_fortnite.png");
    // show stats
    $("#statDisplay").fadeIn(500);
    // clear pre-existing table
    $("#statTable").empty();
    // iterate through the table
    for(let i = 0; i < tableCells.length; i++) {
      // set header row
      $("#statTable").append('<thead> <tr> <th align = "center" colspan = 8> <b> <u>' + gameModes[i] + "</u> </b> </th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr>");
      // intialize stats
      let toAppend;
      // iterate through stats
      for(let j = 0; j < tableCells[i].stats.length; j++) {
        // if there is no sub-category (use different html)
        if(tableCells[i].subcategory === undefined)
          toAppend = ("<td> <b>" + data[tableCells[i].category][tableCells[i].stats[j]].key + ":</b>" + "<br>" + data[tableCells[i].category][tableCells[i].stats[j]].value + "</td>");
        else
          toAppend = ("<td> <b>" + data[tableCells[i].category][tableCells[i].subcategory][tableCells[i].stats[j]].label + ":</b>" + "<br>" + data[tableCells[i].category][tableCells[i].subcategory][tableCells[i].stats[j]].value + "</td>");
        // add html
        $(".statTable").append(toAppend);
      }
      // close table row
      $(".statTable").append("</tr> </tbody>");
    }
    // hide game window
    $("#gameSelect").css("display", "none");
  }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#statTable {
  width: 95%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

#statTable th {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#statTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: grey;
}

#statTable tr:hover td {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class = "standardImage" id = "statDisplay">
    <div name = "statBanner" id = "statBanner" class = "statBanner">
      <img src = "/images/icon_xbox.png" name = "playerIcon" class = "playerIcon" id = "playerIcon" alt = "Player Icon">
      <input name = "playerName" class = "playerName" id = "playerName" readonly>
      <span name = "statButtons" id = "statButtons" class = "statButtons">
        <button name = "backButton" class = "backButton" id = "backButton"> BACK </button>
        <button name = "refreshButton" class = "refreshButton" id = "refreshButton"> REFRESH </button>
      </span>
    </div>
    <table class = "statTable" id = "statTable"> <thead> </thead> <tbody> </tbody> </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Show us the rendered HTML, not the js that attempts to render it.

Comment: Also, I think you misunderstand `.append` - I'd encourage you to check out the docs: http://api.jquery.com/append/ - you can't append partial HTML (opening tags / closing tags).  The markup you are creating is not what you think / expect.

Comment: @cale_b I corrected the post and provided more information. What would the best way to go about getting this corrected?

Comment: @SeniorFluffie Please include all relevant javascript. It would appear `tableCells` is not defined in the source code you have provided. StackoverFlow will allow you to create a working snippet to run your source code (example) if that helps.

Comment: @NewToJS The majority of my code is dependent on data requested from various sites as it is meant for looking up video game stats. However, I will include the entire function if that would help.

Comment: Again `$(".statTable").append("</tr> </tbody>");` - is NOT doing what you expect.  You need to get these working properly, THEN you can focus on the CSS problem.

Comment: Could you not write a small example? Create an object/array with static data to run the example rather than having to use various sites. The main idea is to see how you are building/appending the table but having it functioning in a example would make things much easier to work with and debug.

Comment: Also - you are using `#statTable` in some places, `.statTable` in others.... is it an ID, or a class?

Comment: To get help, you must provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Right now, all we can do is either guess, or else you are asking us to recreate a working example ourselves.

Comment: You can only append an `object`, you cannot append a `string`.

Comment: @cale_b It should have been an ID, however .empty() was not previously working when I kept it as an ID. I'll see what I can do regarding the example.

Comment: @Adriano If I wanted to create multiple elements for the table, as shown in the toAppend line, what would be easiest to implement?

Comment: Maybe use the vanilla js method `appendChild()`: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: Still need the rendered HTML of the _table_ .... (If you figure that out, you'll see what your problem is)

Comment: @cale_b I was able to figure it out a couple of minutes ago with your and Adriano's suggestions. It was fixed by correcting the wrong use of `append()`, using the `css()` function and the `text()` function.